What is a good approach to create a powder dispensing system for a home project?
I have this task where I need to dispense a certain amount of powder (small quantities, around 10g or so), onto trays that are stacked on top of each other with a space of about 20cm between each tray without any human involvement. The purpose of this project is to feed animals on the tray (fish, etc.).
Are there any industry accepted methods of coming up with a design? I was thinking of dispensing using a system like the one made by this designer, but then I come into the issue of how I can move the powder to 5 different trays from one dispenser. I could use a valve system to send the powder down pipes after placing the dispenser above all the trays, but then there is the issue of the powder sticking to the pipe and not completely moving down to the tray.
Are there any tried and tested methods for this task? Thanks in advance.

Is that the only design you have found? May be worth checking for others - like how sugar gets onto buns & biscuits etc
